# Anyone able to integrate Django-Wiki app on Django 3.0.X project?

Tags: django

Has anyone been successful in being able to run the [Django-wiki](https://github.com/django-wiki/django-wiki) app on Django 3.0.1/2 project?. On their docs page, it says that v0.5 supports Django 3.0, but when I try to install it via pip, it downgrades my Django version from 3.0.1 -> 2.2.9. In their requirements file, I see this:

```
Django>=2.2,<3.0
```

If someone is able to get it working, it'd be great if they can point me to some instructions.

Comment: Django 3.x has some code-breaking changes and they mentioned the same in Readme, **Django 3.0 support is pending support in various dependencies.**

Comment: If you want to get rid of the issue (the OP), install django wiki first and then re-install the django using pip command.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out.